# Multi node installation on Openstack

Tags: 16.04, openstack

I was assigned the task of deploying a multi node installation of OpenStack, using the maximum number of three independent physical machines at my disposal. The proposed platform is Ubuntu 16.04. The basic purpose of this proposed cloud deployment is to work as a VM repository, providing VM's  as a working environment for some courses students participate in, as part of the academic services that the university provides.

So my two questions for this matter is as follows:

1) Can anyone suggest a well documented guide (I need this cause im new to OpenStack) for multi node deployment in Ubuntu Linux that is up to date with the latest OpenStack distributions and technologies.

2) I noticed that there is already a guide for Ubuntu here http://docs.openstack.org/liberty/install-guide-ubuntu/index.html. Can anyone tell me if the deployed architecture described inside the guide is eligible to fulfill the needs of the system described above?

Thank you for your time in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [The official openstack install guide for Newton](http://docs.openstack.org/newton/install-guide-ubuntu/) is supposed to be the best documentation. If you think it is not, feel free to join us and improve it :)
   Notice that the latest version at the moment is Newton, not liberty
2. Sure. You can even install an All-in-one OpenStack on a single machine, so your architecture is more than enough to get started. You could for example, use one of the computers as a controller, and the other two as compute nodes. or even install another compute node on the controller.

   If you run into difficulties, maybe you can use some of the tools that automate the steps described in there. For example [training-labs](http://docs.openstack.org/training_labs/) (on VMs) or [BOMSI](https://github.com/julenl/BOMSI) (which can generate self installing ISOs). I recommend you to start by running one of those (or some other installer) and getting a feeling of what OpenStack does, before starting with the installation.

Comment: Thank you for your time. The idea was to use the three machines as follows: 1 machine as Compute node, 1 machine as Storage node (image + volume storage) and the rest of the services needed will rest inside the last machine that would be our Controller node. Is this configuration something that can me covered by the example architecture as described in the official OpenStack guide (http://docs.openstack.org/newton/install-guide-ubuntu/overview.html#example-architecture) ? Also I noticed there is another solution called OpenStack Ansible. Is this better suited to my needs? Thanks for your time.

Comment: When you said "guide" I understood it as an "step by step hands-on" guide, so I mentioned the official documentation. I recommend you this way (typing "apt-get" and editing the config files by hand), because it will give you the best flexibility, and you will learn about how things work.
If what you want is just some tool to install OpenStack, sure OpenStack-Ansible could be a good option. In this context, I also like MaaS/Juju (or Autopilot) from Canonical, but you might be a little short in amount of machines. For 3 machines, you could also use something like DevStack.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, Ubuntu autopilot isn't free. But to be honest, I want to gain experience and knowledge from the process, so I would prefer something not fully automated.

Comment: @V.Georga: Autopilot isn't "free", but you can install up to 10 nodes without paying.  Bug MaaS is AGPLv3, so you can use it to build your OpenStack with juju Charms (also free). I know your situation, I was at the same one two years ago. If you really whant to know how it's done, I recommend you to: 1) Get training-labs installed on your desktop/laptop and 2) Follow the official install guide, and if something does not work, compare your setup with the training-labs one.

Comment: Thank you all these information were very useful!! Again, than you for your time.